# How to use slider in Codename One

Tags: user-interface, widget, slider, codenameone

How can I implement slider widget in Codename One like this:
[image: Slider demo image]

P.S. I need two position slider

Answer (score 2):

Slider in Codename One only supports a single thumb. However, its code is pretty simple. You can just start from that and have 2 thumbs: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Slider.java

Comment: Most easely way to extends Slider to MultipleSlider is override function setProgressInternal, but this function has a private visibility area.